# How to check and set Rest Call Timeout?

Tags: rest-api, callout, apexrest, timeout

my query is timing out, I got info from the documentation that max timeout can be 120 sec and min is 10 second.
How to check and set the new timeout limit?

Comment: req.setTimeout(120*1000);

Comment: Do we have any setting page to set this or only from code we can set the value?

Comment: This is only from code, and only for certain request. Be aware that 120seconds is a total callout duration for all callouts in the execution context